Workflow Set Value on a Multi Select
I am trying to set the Tax Type on Customer record using a workflow. My formula looks like CASE  WHEN {billcountry}=='GB' THEN VAT:S-GB END . The formula throws an error. I tried S-GB, internal field etc. Still the workflow is throwing error. I have also tried TO-CHAR , still it is erroring. Can you please help?

What is the error?  I notice your formula does not have single quotes around the return value, which would cause an error, so that might be it.  Also, in a SQL CASE statement you should use a single equal sign = for comparison - not a double (or triple) equal sign as you would in JavaScript.
